# sql oracle, error "PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored" and "PL/SQL: ORA-00917: missing comma"

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Code:

```
create or replace TRIGGER populate_title
AFTER INSERT
ON SITES


BEGIN 

INSERT INTO sites
( job_title )
VALUES
( (SELECT title FROM jobs WHERE job_id IN (SELECT job_id FROM SITES) );

END;
```

So basically, we are trying to populate a field in the column "job_title" on table "sites," but the information is in another table, "jobs." We have errors and are now stuck. Please help.

Comment: What does the INSERT statement look like with you're using to populate the SITES table? That's where you want to obtain and populate your field, NOT in a trigger. Do not use triggers to implement business logic - this way lies madness.

Comment: Am sure you need `update` instead of `Insert`

Comment: How you are suspecting the error is from `Trigger` what if something wrong in the Original `Insert`

Comment: No we cant even create the trigger because there is an error in the code or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you managed to get this to compile, you would probably have a mutating table problem.

The trigger should be written as a `before insert` trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER populate_title
BEFORE INSERT
ON SITES
BEGIN 
    SELECT j.title INTO :NEW.job_title
    FROM jobs j
    WHERE j.job_id = :NEW.job_id;
END;
```

However, a trigger for this is *ludicrous*.  The right way to get this information is to query and use `JOIN`:

```
select s.*, j.title
from sites s join
     jobs j
     on s.job_id = j.job_id;
```

Comment: We're not trying to retrieve this information, but rather insert it from another table in a attempt to avoid human error.

Comment: @ScottLeslie . . . Using `JOIN`s prevents human error.  Having the same attribute in multiple tables is sloppy and allows for inconsistent data -- unless that is your intention.